# Use split function to show each value in seperate row

Tags: sql, sql-server, split, sql-server-2014

Consider I have already created `dbo.split` function which operate like this:

Query:

```
select substr from dbo.split(',' , 'A,B,C')
```

Result:

```
|Substr|
--------
|A     |
--------
|B     |
--------
|C     |
--------
```

Now I want to use this function to convert this table:

```
|ID|Char|
---------
|1 |A,B |
---------
|2 |A   |
---------
|3 |B,C |
---------
```

to this result:

```
|ID|Char|
---------
|1 |A   |
---------
|1 |B   |
---------
|2 |A   |
---------
|3 |B   |
---------
|3 |C   |
---------
```

Comment: I'm thinking you need to loop through all records in table and use your split function on each row and insert results from split into another table which will be in your desired form.

Comment: You need to add some code that you have already written

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

This works without `Split` function.

```
 DECLARE @Table TABLE(ID INT, [Char] VARCHAR(20))
 INSERT INTO @Table VALUES(1,'A,B')
 INSERT INTO @Table VALUES(2,'A')
 INSERT INTO @Table VALUES(3,'B,C')

SELECT A.ID,  
     Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS [Char]  
 FROM  
 (
     SELECT ID,  
         CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE([Char], ',', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS Data  
     FROM  @Table
 ) AS A CROSS APPLY Data.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have a `dbo.split` function you can use `CROSS APPLY` to obtain the desired output:

```
DECLARE @tmp TABLE(ID INT, [Char] VARCHAR(50))
INSERT INTO @tmp VALUES(1,'A,B'), (2,'A'), (3,'B,C')

select T.[ID], D.[Substr] 
from @tmp T cross apply [dbo].[Split](',', T.[Char]) D
```

Results:

[image]